# Python Path in virtualenv

Tags: python, path, virtualenv, pythonpath

I'm runnning a **virtualenv** in the django-web folder. The folder has a **Scripts** folder which contains the *python* file **django-admin.py**. I would like to run this *python* file as: **python django-admin.py** from C:\Users\name\django-web with the **virtualenv** activated. The python file isn't found unfortunatly:

```
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

when I look for the pythonpath in my virtual env:

> (django-web) C:\Users\name\django-web>python Python 3.4.1
>   (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
>   tel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
>   more information. import sys; print(sys.path) ['',
>   'C:\Users\name\django-web\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.5-py3.4.egg'
>   , 'C:\Python34\Lib', 'C:\Python34\DLLs',
>   'C:\Windows\system32\python34.zi p',
>   'C:\Users\name\django-web\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\name\django-web\lib', 
>   **'C:\Users\name\django-web\Scripts'**, 'C:\Users\name\django-web', 'C:\
>   \Users\name\django-web\lib\site-packages']

The path **'C:\Users\name\django-web\Scripts'** where the file is located is clearly in the python path.

Running the file as python **Scripts\django-admin.py** from C:\Users\name\django-web runs fine.

Comment: When you run a script like this, `PYTHONPATH` is irrelevant; `PYTHONPATH` is only used when *importing* inside a Python script or module, not when finding executables or scripts. You should indeed run the script with its full path, as you mention in the last line. Alternatively, you'd have to make sure your `PATH` environment variable includes `C:\Users\name\django-web\Scripts`, and then you should be able to simple run `django-admin.py` (without `Scripts\` or `python ` prepended.

Comment: @Evert that should have been an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, PYTHONPATH helps Python to find required modules while importing.
In your case it does not matter because you are trying to run the script, it is not an import
seems like you are executing `python django-admin.py` in wrong directory.
Also you have to run virtualenv's python binary instead of regular one (just need to activate virtualenv)

[virtual env HOW TO](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-virtualenv-usage)